# How to save data of FutureProvider to avoid rebuild

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I am using `FutureProvider` to fetch data(places) from `Laravel API` to show that data in flutter. Now the problem is it is rebuilding again and again that even server started throwing error of `"too many attempts"`. I am using `ListView.builder` to show all places fetch from API but when I scroll to next places and then scroll back to previous it rebuilds. Mean `FutureProvider` is rebuilding again and again. Here is code attached. I also tried to add `addAutomaticKeepAlives: true,` in ListView to save the state

```
Container(
  height: 100,
  child: ListView.builder(
    addAutomaticKeepAlives: true,
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    itemCount: places.length,
    itemBuilder: (_, index) {
      return FutureProvider(
        initialData: null,
        
        create: (context) =>
            getFireIceCount(index, places),
        child: Consumer<List<dynamic>>(
          builder: (context, fireIceCount,
              child) {
            return (fireIceCount != null)
                ? (fireIceCount.isNotEmpty)
                    ? PlacesImageViewer()
                    : Center(
                        child:
                            CircularProgressIndicator(
                          color:
                              Colors.cyan,
                        ),
                      )
                : Center(
                    child:
                        CircularProgressIndicator(
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
                  );
          },
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need a stateful widget, because the `State` object associated with it is maintained between rebuilds. The first advice would be to extract the widget you are building out of the listview itself

```
class SampleItem extends StatefulWidget {
  const SampleItem({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SampleItemState createState() => _SampleItemState();
}

class _SampleItemState extends State<SampleItem> {
  late final Future<List<dynamic>> items=getFireIceCount(index, places);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BuildYOurItemHere();
  }
}
```

But the most important thing would be actually making less requests to the backend, fetch a range of items instead of one by one, and try to implement pagination [both in your](https://pub.dev/packages/infinite_scroll_pagination) app and the server. This single handedly will decrease the times you hit the server, increase the performance as you are making less requests.